# Creating list of values based on user inputs VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a list of data going in increments of 0.01 from 0 to whatever the number inputed by the user is. I keep getting a runtime error.
`

```
Sub DataCollect()
'Collecting Values
Sheets("sheet1").Select
Range("A1").Select
a = ActiveCell.Value
Range("A2").Select
b = AvtiveCell.Value
i = 3
x = 0
For x = 0 To a Step 0.01
    Cells(i, 1).Value = x
    i = i + 1
Next x
End Sub
```

`

what is the error in my code?

Comment: `b = ActiveCell.Value`

Comment: Man this is embarrassing, thanks homie